# How to change i18next default language in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, i18next

i18n default language  is english or `en` how can i change it from configuration?

here is my configuration

```
import i18n from "i18next";
import Backend from "i18next-xhr-backend";
import LanguageDetector from "i18next-browser-languagedetector";
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";

const fallbackLng = ["nl"];
const availableLanguages = ["nl", "en"];

i18n
  .use(Backend) 
  .use(LanguageDetector) 
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    fallbackLng, 
    debug: false,
    whitelist: availableLanguages,
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false,
    },
  });

export default i18n;
```

Comment: fyi: whitelist property and als i18next-xhr-backend are deprecated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i18next [Configuration Options](https://www.i18next.com/overview/configuration-options) suggests to use `lng` option to override language detection in this way:

```
i18n
  .use(Backend) 
  .use(LanguageDetector) 
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    lng: 'nl', 
    debug: false,
    whitelist: availableLanguages,
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false,
    },
  });
```

This should solve your problem.